# Can't see source code for ES6 and TypeScript libraries in Chrome DevTools

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I am distributing my ES6 and TypeScript libraries with source maps as well as the associated source files. However when such a library is installed in an app (under `node_modules`), the Chrome debugger shows the compiled JavaScript output instead of the original source file. How can I make the debugger show the original source file?

Here's the distribution of one of my TypeScript libraries:

[image]

As you can see I have `index.js.map` and `router-store.js.map` in the `dist` directory. These maps point to the corresponding TypeScript files in the src directory, e.g.

```
"sources":["../src/index.ts"]
```

In spite of this, when I look at the app in Chrome Debugger, the file name shows as `index.js` and contains the compiled JavaScript output. See below:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you bundling the app overall? If it's Webpack, you potentially need to use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader

Comment: Yes, the app is bundled using Webpack. It is actually created by create-react-app. I don't think it is using source-map-loader. If I eject, I see that in uses `devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'` in the Webpack config.

Comment: I configured webpack to use source-map-loader and `devtool: 'source-map'`, but no luck :-(

Answer (score 1):

I do not see my files in the Sources file tree either, but (and I'm on a Mac), if I do Command+O I can search for my file, by name, and Dev Tools will show it, allowing me to add breakpoints and step through code.

Comment: Yep, I am on a mac too and yes, command+O let's you search for a file. However, the point I am making is that the version of the file that is displayed is the compiled (ES5) version, not the original ES6 or TypeScript version.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `devtool: 'source-map'`, so maybe that's why.